# Express (sequelize) export async function

Tags: javascript, function, express, asynchronous, sequelize.js

I'm very new to express / NodeJS in general. I started to write a little application, providing a REST API. The whole thing should work like this:

- the request gets routed (routes.js)
- in routes.js, a function in a controller gets called
- since my controller contains the app's logic, it should return data that gets sent with res.json(CONTROLLER_FUNCTION()).

My code:

controller.js

```
User = require('../models/user')

module.exports.users = function users() {
    users = User.findAll().then(users => {
    return users;
});
```

}

routes.js

```
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json(userController.users())
});
```

So when my route gets called, nothing happens. I believe that happens because my controller logic is async. Probably I have to implement something like a wrapper/callback function (?)

So basically my question is: what is the "right" way to handle a situation like this? How should my code look like?

Example:
What I normally would do is to pass to userController.users a function, that gets called when the async action is done (.then).

routes.js

```
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  userController.users((data) => res.json(data));
});
```

controller.js

```
User = require('../models/user')

module.exports.users = function users(send) {
    users = User.findAll().then(users => {
        send(users);
    });
}
```

Is this the best way to do this? / Is this considered good practice? Is it even recommended to not put my code directly into routes.js?

Comment: Technically, your example is correct. On the other hand, you have to look overall what libraries you are using, and stick to common denominator. For instance, in this specific case, I would not pass the callback to `userController.users`. I would simply return promise, as it is returning from `User.findAll()`. Because, if most libraries are promise based, you can chain them, combine them etc. And call `res.json()` only in the end, in the routes. This is just for illustration purposes. Everybody, picks his own best practice as seems fit. You can also look at libraries like `promisify`.

Comment: @muradm thanks for your input! I also thought about using promises and jsut returning `User.findAll()` in my controller, then calling `userCcontroller.users().then...` in my routes.js. The only thing that lets my thinking wheter this is a good solution is, that also this approach lets me write my logic into my controller. Do you think regardless of that this approach is better?

Comment: that all depends on your application. In your place, I would not stick to `what if` controller this or logic that, because when you do it beforehand, most likely you will fall to over-engineering trap. Just do it, start doing your application, draw like 5-10 methods, make it work. Then revise. Then do next 5-10, then revise all, and so on. After some time you will have your intuition and your best practice :) best practice comes with practice :)

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports.getUsers = async () => {
   const users = await User.findAll();

   return users; 
}
```

Comment: Hmm, sorry, but this doesn't work for me. I tried it, but always got an empty object {}.

Comment: @AGuyAskingQuestions Of course it doesn't, the answer mixes up async/await and promises (and the entire .then block is redundant). module.exports.getUsers = async () => { const users = await User.findAll(); return users; } should work with userController.getUsers().then(res.json) in your routes.js. Also, you really shouldn't be defining your array with the same name as your function, look into using [eslint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started) and an eslint extension for your code editor to avoid these sort of things and make it easier to follow best practice.

Comment: I have been updated my answer based on `async` and  `await` syntax.

Comment: @Asifvora Right, but the handler in routes.js still doesn't know it's getting an async function, so that also needs to be changed to either (req, res) => userController.getUsers().then(res.json) or async (req, res) => { const users = await userController.getUsers(); return res.json(users) }